# PDA and Some language Grammar inference

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, regular-language, turing-machines

L1={$w^* $| w=x and $ x \in \Sigma^*$}

L2={$ww^R ww^R $| $ w \in ( \Sigma  + \Sigma)^*$}

L3={$w | w=xy, x,y \in \Sigma^*$, y is a substring of x}

a) there is a PDA(push down automata) that accept L2 intersection L3

b) there is a PDA(push down automata) that accept L2 union L3

c) there is a PDA(push down automata) that accept L1 intersection L3

d) there is a PDA(push down automata) that accept L1 union L3

I think (a) is false. can I say 3 and 4 is wrong because we have no language that not closed under union but closed under intersection?

anyone can help me with some detail about the answer of this question?

Comment: I'd say the first step is to decide which of $L1, L2, L3$ is context-free.  Once you've done that you can use the closure properties of CFLs to help you decide the answer to your four questions.  But notice that $L1$ is particularly simple, so its intersection with the other languages may be simpler than it first appears. The reason you give at the end, “we have no language that not closed under union but closed under intersection” does not make sense to me.

Comment: Dear @MJD, would you please submit a nice detail for each of them as an answer? one of my friends say 3 and 4 is false because it's not possible to have a language that not closed under union but closed on intersection that raise a conflict between (3) and (4).

Comment: No, I will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Dear @MJD, which homework is multiple choice? I create this test because gather all situation for difference between CFG and Regular Grammar. I just want to learn about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that $L_1$ is really simple:

$$L_1=\{w^* \mid w=x\text{ and  }x \in \Sigma^*\}\supseteq\{w^1 \mid w=x\text{ and  }x \in \Sigma^*\} =\Sigma^*$$
Hence $L_1=\Sigma^*$.

Then notice that$L_3$ is also really simple:

$$L_3=\{w \mid w=x.y, x,y \in \Sigma^*, y\text{ is a sub-string of }x\}$$

If as sub-string you allows $\epsilon$, then you van decompose any word $w$ as $w.\epsilon$ hence $L_3=\Sigma^*$.

Otherwise notice that if $y=y_1\dots y_n$ is a sub-string of $x$ then $y_n$ is a sub-string of $x$ hence also of $x.y_1\dots y_{n-1}$. Hence you only have to check that the last letter appear at least once other time in the word. Hence $L_3$ is regular.

Since $L_1$ and $L_3$ are regulars I let you find the answers for c) and d).

For a) and b) notice that $L_2\subseteq L_3$. Then you have to know whether $L_2$ is context free or not ...

For b) L2 is included in L3 so what is the result of the union?.

For c) and d) what do you know about union and intersection of regular language? (if nothing L1=Σ∗ so the union and intersection are pretty simple)

Comment: Dear wece, at first thanks, next, would you please clarify about a,b,c,d? I means each of them is false or true? to approve it.

Comment: What would you say?

Comment: (a) is false. but I expect to some one about (a) to (d) hint. for example a could not be true because... a short sentence about each of them.

Comment: ok. For a) if you know the answer then I think you have what you want. For b) $L_2$ is included in $L_3$ so what is the result of the union?. For c) and d) what do you know about union and intersection of regular language? (if nothing $L_1=\Sigma^*$ so the union and intersection are pretty simple).

Comment: Dear wece, it's better to complete your answer :) not ask another question, I know this is simple and get my answer, but for others who read, please complete it at the end of your inference about (a) to (d)

Comment: This site is not done to give answers on homework problem. I think that my response is appropriated. The things that could have been missed are written, and what is left is just basic properties on cfl and regular languages

Comment: Okey, thanks so much.

Comment: Dear @wece, would you please complete your answer?